# How to use the youtube iFrame player API with Angular 2+?

Tags: angular, typescript, iframe, youtube

I am trying to follow the youtube player api [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) and am having difficult implementing it with Angular 4.

One of my components has a youtube video in which it needs to do various things to it such as start the video at a specific time, automatically pause, play etc. I know that I can load a youtube video and use the API inside a component's template directly like so:

```
<iframe 
  id="player"
  type="text/html"
  width="420" 
  height="315" 
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k?autoplay=1&controls=1&disablekb=0"
  frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

but how would I have access to its state changes in the component's corresponding .ts file? Can I access the video within the typescript file by using the iframe's id value that I gave it?

I am also fine with using packages such as this [one](https://github.com/gajus/youtube-player#examples) but the examples don't explain how to use it with components. I am sure that my issue is stemming from misunderstanding of how Angular 2+ works and I would appreciate any help.